# text_size in multiple screen support

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I'm trying to decrease the text size of a textview depending on the device the app runs. However I can't make it work.

I created the folder values-sw320dp (also tried values-w320dp) and put inside the dimens.xml file

```
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">25sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

and my values/dimens.xml file contains

```
<dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
```

What I expect is to load the app in Nexus One (emulator), which is 482 x 320 dp, and get the text size 18sp. However I get text size 25sp.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create folder as `values-hdpi`

**dimens.xml**  for  values-hdpi

```
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And  Create folder as `values-xhdpi`

**dimens.xml**  for  values-xhdpi

```
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">25sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

And use like this-

```
android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
```

Comment: values-hdpi is deprecated in favour of swXXXdp if i'm not wrong

Comment: Please see this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
Nothing as deprecated on official website.

Answer (score 0):

I use `values-hdpi`, `values-mdpi`, `values-ldpi`, `values-xlarge`

Comment: They are deprecated in favour of swXXXdp, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

Nexus One has dimension 480 x 800, so try 
values-sw360dp

Comment: Why sw360dp? 480 x 800px is equivalent to 320 x 482 dp, then sw320dp should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Create folder as `values-sw600dp` and `values-sw720dp` in res folder.

**dimens.xml** for values-sw600dp

```
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">4sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**dimens.xml** for values-sw720dp

```
<resources>
<dimen name="text_size">6sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense with respect to the question